# Model class and Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, fluent

I have the Client class defined. I also have Mapping\ClientMap.cs file that defines column names using Fluent API. However, I am not sure how to "invoke" it as I don't see the ClientMap.cs code being executed.

I also have this:

```
namespace CardNumbers.Data
{
    public class Repository : DbContext, IRepository
    {
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClientOrder> ClientOrders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Reorder> Reorders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
```

which I know is not a very good practice, but that's how we were building the application with the instructor.

So, my question is - what do I need to add to make sure the Fluent API code is invoked in run-time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fluent mapping should be added at the bottom of your "`Repository`" class like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //add fluent api code
    }
```

The reason I am quoting your Repository is that you are not really implementing a repository pattern there. You should really have this defined as a specific DbContext, and then have a repository which can take multiple contexts. See this very well written post about implementing a repository: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you, I am going to re-design, luckily I haven't progressed a lot yet in development, so I can still switch.

Comment: I've re-designed, but now I am getting SQL Server error which I was not getting before.

Comment: @Naomi - Can you make a new question for this with the corresponding code and the exact error you get?

Comment: Please take a look at the very bottom message here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/6a9cc309-5767-4db4-a039-fb7f17d13821 I posted the whole error and my DbContext class. I am following the example from the tutorial

Comment: Never mind, I figured this out, it's working now, so I can test in my Web Application.

Comment: @ Travis J Unfortunately, looks like the whole re-design was in vain as now I can not get e-mail validations to show up properly.

Comment: @Naomi - That issue seems to be in your view. Are you sure you are including the `ValidationMessageFor` razor helper?

Comment: Yes, I do. My EditorFor classes for the textboxes are based on this blog post http://fusionovation.com/post/2010/02/15/adding-a-rich-text-editor-to-asp-net-mvc-using-strongly-typed-helpers-dataannotations-amp-jquery.aspx and my ContactDetail EditorFor has calls to these EditorFor for their components

Comment: Is there any way we can continue this conversation either through chat or by e-mail?

Comment: I think the problem can be in the fact that my page now has 2 email Ids (inside different divs).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016674/validations-not-show-up-using-ef-code-first-with-complex-types

Comment: BTW, want to thank you again. I re-designed using that blog and I got my validations working.

Answer (score 2):

You should place your mapping code either directly in your [OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method (which is a virtual method you can override on `DbContext`), or place it in a sepearte configuration class which is then invoked from the `OnModelCreating` method.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
}
```

or

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClientConfiguration());
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
public class ClientConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public ClientConfiguration()
    {          
        this.Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question - can the question have only 1 accepted answer? If I click on the checkbox to accept one of the answers, the other loses the checkmark.

Comment: After re-design I get this error InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            HResult=-2146232060
            Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)